# Representation of a group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a affine algebraic group scheme(may not be reductive) over a scheme $S$. How to define a rational representaion of $\mathcal{G}$ (over $S$)? Is there always a faithful representation?

Please provide references related to these questions.

Comment: What if $S$ is $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is an Abelian variety?  Do you want to add a hypothesis that $\mathcal{G}$ is a closed subgroup scheme of $\textbf{GL}_{n,S}$, or at least that it is affine over $S?$

Comment: I believe it remains an unsolved problem to determine if all smooth affine group schemes over the ring $k[\epsilon]$ of dual numbers over a field arise as a closed subgroup scheme of some ${\rm{GL}}_n$.  So that device which is so useful over fields is not available more generally.  Anyway, one can always contemplate $S$-group homomorphisms $\mathcal{G} \to {\rm{GL}}_n$ (even if no interesting ones exist), but calling these "rational representations" sounds weird when the base isn't a field.

Comment: I strongly agree with nfdc23's comment and especially the last part.    I'm unaware of any setting in which one has to consider "rational representations" over a base that isn't at least a commutative ring such as a field.    For example, since Jantzen's book is about representation theory, he has no need to work in greater generality over arbitrary schemes.    A field is usually complicated enough.

Comment: For further discussion see Aside 9.4 in Chapter 9, in Milne, "Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes":
www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your current sources are, but the definitions are laid out clearly in SGA3 (by Demazure and Grothendieck) and similarly in the book by Demazure and Gabriel, *Groupes algebriques* (North-Holland, 1970) which was later published in an English translation.   (Their designation of this book as "Tome I" is of course unfortunate, since it had no sequel.)

In Demazure-Gabriel, one finds for example an explicit statement about the existence (over a field) of a faithful linear representation, in the affine case:  see II, 5.2.    This is far into their book but is fairly elementary, just relying on the basic notions.

For a treatment heavily influenced by Demazure-Gabriel (or SGA3), you can also consult the early sections of Jantzen's book *Representations of Algebraic Groups* (Academic Press, 1987; 2nd enlarged edition, Amer. Math. Soc., 2003).    See especially I.2 for the notion of rational representation of a group scheme (over any commutative ring).

I should add that Jim Milne has developed a modern textbook version of all this, probably published by now; check his webpage for details: http://www.jmilne.org/math/

Comment: Yes, Milne's book has [appeared](https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Groups-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/1107167485/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1510588185&sr=1-1&keywords=J.S.+Milne).